# Why was this question closed as "off-topic"?

Tags: support

Please keep answers on-topic, meaning that they're limited to why the question was closed as off-topic, since that is the issue at hand, and until that is addressed, no other reasons relate to why it was closed.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24466/how-to-research-payment-collect-methods

Comment: Question deleted?

Comment: @danlefree If John doesn't intend to address this(I don't care one way or the other), could a mod at least kill it, so the system stops bumping it? The asker has made it clear nothing's going to be accepted except a direct response from John(given he's the one who closed the original, only he actually knows the answer), so it's basically stuck in an irritating "who's more stubborn" purgatory.

Comment: The original question was "For the average business, how should they identify their payment processing requirements, and research related payment collect methods?" and, given this site's scope the question would be off-topic (though, if the general scope of another SE site encompassed this topic, the question would still need to be revised to avoid being closed as not constructive). Closing meta discussion per request.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why the question was closed as "off topic", flags don't appear in the timelines as far as I can tell, and beyond the mod there were no other votes to close.

Going by RandomBen's comment, "Not Constructive" would have been a better close option:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

There **are** similar questions already on here, and I'd have thought that this was a good topic - albeit the question could do with a little tidying (grammar in the title, add the [ecommerce](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce) and/or [payment-gateway](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-gateway) to it)

- [What payment gateways fit my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/22960/60)
- [Accepting money on a website as payment: when do I move past PayPal?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/7/60)

To be honest, the first one (about options) is probably closest to your request - the answer certainly gives you some things to consider - and so the question might better have been closed as a duplicate of that.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but I very clearly stated I wanted to know why it was closed as off-topic and not other reasons why it might have been closed; please take to heart take I rarely downvote, but in this case I'm completely puzzled, and want to know why so I'm able to address the issue. As such while your thoughts are well stated, they do do not answer the question, John is the only one that's able to answer the question, as you state.

Comment: @blunders No problem - down votes on per-site-metas are different to main: because they are more "I agree/disagree" and don't impact rep - I knew it's not the answer you are looking for, however perhaps it will provide some guidance to others when it comes to voting to close, etc. to choose their reasons with care :)